# Getting video file details using FileReader

Tags: javascript, video, filereader

I have a web-based user interface facilitating dragging and dropping files into a container DIV. If the dropped file is an image, I use the following code:

```
let droppedFile = evt.dataTransfer.files[0];
let img = new Image();
let reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function() {
  img.src = reader.result;
  let fileDetails = {};
  let n = droppedFile.name.indexOf('.');
  fileDetails.name = droppedFile.name.substring(0, n != -1 ? n : droppedFile.name.length);
  fileDetails.extension = droppedFile.name.substring(n != -1 ? n+1 : '');
  fileDetails.fileType = droppedFile.type;
  fileDetails.width = img.naturalWidth;
  fileDetails.height = img.naturalHeight;
  // display fileDetails in another DIV...
}
reader.readAsDataURL(droppedFile);
```

I need to be able to do the same thing with a video file (e.g. an MP4). However, I don't see any `Video` element, similar to the [Image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) element/constructor. How do I go about instantiating a video element, so I can get the generic attributes as well as video specific attributes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use FileReader. Use the following code:

```
const video = document.createElement('video')
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', event => {
  console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight)
})
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(droppedFile)
```

Full code:

```js
const dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone')
dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', event => event.preventDefault())
dropzone.addEventListener('drop', event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  const droppedFile = event.dataTransfer.files[0]
  const video = document.createElement('video')
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', event => {
   console.log(video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight)
  })
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(droppedFile)
})
```

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#dropzone {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px dashed blue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  color: gray;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition: 400ms;
}
#dropzone:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropzone">drop files here</div>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to not only get the metadata, but also upload it to the server shortly after, when the user finishes reviewing the metadata and clicks on an upload button? In that case, would I need to use the FileReader API?

Comment: @WebUser Yes.​‌​‌‍

Answer (score 1):

```
 var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      var videoElement = document.createElement('video');
      videoElement.src = e.target.result;
      var timer = setInterval(() => {
        if (videoElement.readyState === 4) {
          if(videoElement.duration) {
            console.log(file)//the file object
            console.log(videoElement.duration) //video duration
          }
          clearInterval(timer);
        }
      }, 500)
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```